# Query Return Only One value In Count php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hi guys the query only return one rows even i have 12 rows. Please help

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
$qry="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $qry);
```

Comment: COUNT is an aggregation function, it's going to aggregate all rows unless you use groupings.

Comment: You dont actually get the information that that query returns. You need to do some sort of fetch to get the actual count

Answer (score -2):

As Devon mentioned, COUNT is an aggregate function, so it will only return 1 row. If you want to retrieve all 12 rows, do:

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```